# div auto increase height not working

Tags: javascript, html, object

i have try this to my project but have some problem in this div enlargement. i need to stop DIV scroll bar and make full height scroll with browser scroll bar

home.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="funcition.js"></script>
<div id="header">This is Header Section</div>
<div id="sider"></div>
<div id="full_page">
    <object data="test.php"></object>
</div>
<div id="footer">This Is footer section</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Style.css

```
#footer
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#bo
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
}
#full_page
{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 1000px;
}
```

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="funcition.js"></script>
<div id="bo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to enlarge #full_page to occupy 100% of rhe page?

Comment: #full_page or OBJECT tag i need to remove DIV scroll bar and 100% height of content size

Answer (score 0):

Please try this styles.

```
#footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0px; z-index:99; }
#bo { width: 200px; height: auto; background-color: red; }
#full_page { height:auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If im right the answer is very simple:

```
#full_page{
    height: auto;
    overflow:none;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is happening when the document has loaded?

Comment: see the image when page loads it will activate scroll bar

Comment: you have remove the max-height:1000px; for this to work

Comment: #full_page 
{ 
 height: auto;
    overflow:none;
 background-color: blue;
}

Comment: Alright then try this:  #full_page object { height: auto; overflow:none; background-color: blue; }

Comment: overflow has only these function (overflow: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit;) none is incorrect

Comment: * {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
}
html, body{
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
}
object 
 { 
    overflow : hidden;
 }

Comment: I think you should search how to hide the scrollbar instead of this question which has many answers in SO ..and they maybe helpful